# Is there any possibility to open a dialog when clicking on a textField in MaterialUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, material-ui, textfield

I want to make a textField clickable so that a dialog box opens for the user to type in more text.

Do you have any idea how can I make that happen with the help of MaterialUI?

This is my current solution, where a button is displayed to open the dialogbox (instead of making the textField itself clickable):

```
<form noValidate autoComplete="off">
          <TextFieldDialog />
          <TextField
            id="outlined-multiline-static"
            label="Frage"
            multiline
            rows={4}
            placeholder="Tippe hier die Frage ein!"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            variant="outlined"
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "white",
            }}
          >
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe an [input adornmant](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#input-adornments) that is clickable.

Comment: Can you not just use `onClick` or `onFocus`? e.g. `onClick={showDialog}`

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `onClick` on `TextField`

```js
const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState(false)

return (
  <div>
    <TextField
      id="outlined-basic"
      label="Outlined"
      variant="outlined"
      onClick={() => setDialogOpen(true)}
    />
    <Dialog open={dialogOpen} onClose={() => setDialogOpen(false)}>
      <DialogTitle>Sample Dialog</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent dividers>
        <Typography>Your content here</Typography>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  </div>
)
```

Codesandbox demo

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]